# The instance member 'value' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am hoping to use *value* passed on from another widget in one of the references for a collection within a document. However, this error pops up:

> The instance member 'value' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

How should I go about this?

```
class FriendProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  String value;
  FriendProfileScreen({Key? key, required this.value}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FriendProfileScreenState createState() => _FriendProfileScreenState(value);
}

class _FriendProfileScreenState extends State<FriendProfileScreen> {
  String value;
  _FriendProfileScreenState(this.value);

  var uid = value;
  final CollectionReference _todoref = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(value)
      .collection("todos");
  @override
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to mark it late, so like

```
  late final CollectionReference _todoref = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(value)
      .collection("todos");
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your initializing code into a future type function and call the function in init method. It will work.

```
 var uid;    
 Future loadData()async{
 uid = value;
 final CollectionReference _todoref = FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection("users")
  .doc(value)
  .collection("todos");
}
@override
  void initState() {
    loadData();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: ive thought of doing this to but cant put my mind to it. thank you ill try this too!

Comment: I use this approach for loading all required data for the page instead of loading using late variables or calling directly inside initstate. It gives me flexiblity of loading bulk of data even from multiple providers as well.